# Does Celery task code need to exist on multiple machines?

Tags: celery

Trying to wrap my head around Celery.  So far I understand that there is the Client, Broker, and Worker(s).  For simplicity, I'm looking at a [Dockerized version of this setup](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

If I understand correctly, the client enqueues a task on the broker, then the worker continuously attempts to pop from the broker and process the task.

In the example, it seems like both the [Client (in this case a Flask app)](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask/blob/master/snakeeyes/blueprints/contact/tasks.py#L8) and the [Worker](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L40), reference the [exact same code](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask/blob/master/snakeeyes/blueprints/contact/views.py#L22).  Is that correct?

Does this mean that if each of the components were broken out into their own machines that the code would need to be deployed to both Client and Worker machines at the same time?  It seems strange that these pieces would need to access the same task/function to do their respective work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one thing I was initially confused by as well. The tasks' code doesn't have to be present on both, only the worker needs the code to do the actual work. When you say that client enqueues the task on broker which worker then executes, it's crucial to understand how this works. The client only sends a message to the broker, not an actual task. The message contains task name, arguments and other stuff. So the client needs to know just these parameters about the task to enqueue it. Then, it can use [`send_task`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) to enqueue the task without knowing.

This is how I employ Celery in a simple jobber application where I want to decouple the pieces as much as possible. I have a Flask app that serves as a UI for the jobs which users can manage (create, see the state/progress etc.) The Flask app uses APScheduler to actually run the jobs (where a job is nothing else than a Celery task). Now, I want the client part (Flask app + scheduler) to know only as little as possible about the tasks to run them as jobs. That means their names and arguments they can take. To make it really independent of the tasks' code, I get this information from the workers via the broker. You can see a little bit more background from [this issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5363) I initially created.